# What does this higher-ranked trait bound mean?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

In Salsa, there is a higher-ranked trait bound on a trait. I've seen HRTBs on function definitions but not on a trait. What does it mean?

```rs
pub trait Query: Debug + Default + Sized + for<'d> QueryDb<'d> {
...
    fn query_storage<'a>(
        group_storage: &'a <Self as QueryDb<'_>>::GroupStorage,
    ) -> &'a Arc<Self::Storage>;
}
```

https://github.com/salsa-rs/salsa/blob/fc6806a/src/lib.rs#L370

As in, how should I read this? Is it saying that, for any `Query`, there is a corresponding `QueryDB` that has *some* lifetime?

How is this different from

```rs
pub trait Query<'d>: Debug + Default + Sized + QueryDb<'d>
```

aside from that impls cannot specify `'d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how should I read this?

It means that any implementation of `Query` also implements `QueryDb<'d>` *for all possible values of `'d` (i.e. all lifetimes) at once*. Therefore, in a generic context, the trait bound `T: Query` implies `T: for<'d> QueryDb<'d>`.

> How is this different from
>
> ```
> pub trait Query<'d>: Debug + Default + Sized + QueryDb<'d>
> ```
>
> aside from that impls cannot specify `'d`?

By repeating the lifetime parameter on `Query`, it means that all trait bounds `T: Query` will need to be changed to `T: for<'d> Query<'d>` in order to be equivalent to the version where the HRTB is in `Query` itself.

This is basically [a workaround for the lack of generic associated types](https://github.com/salsa-rs/salsa/pull/242#pullrequestreview-457679157). With generic associated types, `QueryDb` would instead look like this:

```
pub trait QueryDb: Sized {
    /// Dyn version of the associated trait for this query group.
    type DynDb<'d>: ?Sized + Database + HasQueryGroup<Self::Group> + 'd;

    /// Associate query group struct.
    type Group: plumbing::QueryGroup<GroupStorage = Self::GroupStorage>;

    /// Generated struct that contains storage for all queries in a group.
    type GroupStorage;
}
```

Before the [pull request](https://github.com/salsa-rs/salsa/pull/242) that introduced this lifetime parameter, `QueryDb` wasn't a separate trait; its members were part of `Query`. The generic associated type would allow us to merge `QueryDb` back into `Query`.

After reading the comments on that pull request, I get the impression that this change didn't yield the expected results. The goal was to allow a bound different from the implied `'static` on associated type `DynDb`, but since every `Query` implements `QueryDb<'d>` for all possible `'d`, that means every `Query` implements `QueryDb<'static>`. Therefore, in all implementations of `QueryDb`, the `DynDb` cannot possibly borrow anything with a lifetime shorter than `'static`, otherwise the implementation of `Query` wouldn't be allowed (the bound `for<'d> QueryDb<'d>` wouldn't be satisfied).

Comment: is this obsolete in new code now that Rust 1.65 has GATs?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the type in the argument for `query_storage`:

```
Self as QueryDb<'_>
```

From the nomicon:

> `for<'a>` can be read as "for all choices of 'a", and basically produces an infinite list of trait bounds that F must satisfy.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html

Comment: But this can be `Self as QueryDb<'d>` if `trait Query<'d>: ... + QueryDb<'d>`!

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question, would you be up for elaborating?